# Validating Phone Numbers C#

Tags: c#

Given a list of phone numbers, let’s say the phone number is 91 12 34 56, it’s not possible to call it right? Because of the emergency line.

I am trying to build a program that if the user inputs a phone number that starts with 911, the output should be "NOT CONSISTENT" otherwise "CONSISTENT".

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var phoneList = new List<string>();
    string input;
    Console.WriteLine("The Phone Number: ");

    while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        phoneList.Add(input);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < phoneList.Count; j++)
        {
            if (phoneList[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals(phoneList[j].Substring(0, 3)) && i != j)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT CONSISTENT");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CONSISTENT");
}
```

My program just jumps over the `if` statement as soon as I type 911. Why is that?

Edit: A phone number is a sequence of at most ten digits also!

Comment: You don't check `911` anywhere, you're only checking the list of numbers against itself. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Before you try to write any more code. 1) you are validating strings, not integers/numbers. If you are ever unsure which it is ask yourself will you ever perform a mathematical operation on it, if that's not likely then you have a string. 2) The most common method to validate string input is to use Regular Expressions and there are plenty of tutorials out there: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regular%20expressions%20tutorial

Comment: Could you provide some examples for which you code is expected to print "consistent" and some for which its not? Because I can't quite understand how valid input looks like.

Comment: Phone numbers are not integers, they're strings. Leading zeroes and length are both significant in phone numbers. They also include control characters for extensions and menu-trees. Don't forget the * and # symbols too.

Comment: Yes so I learned that a phone number should be a string. Anyway, im putting a breakpoint and debugging, and it just goes through an infinte loop and never exits the while statement. And I dont think that RegEx validation would help in this case right? Because using RegEx I need a class with properties and call an instance of that class object in my main method correct?

Comment: As others have commented, try treating it as a fully joined single string: `string phoneNumber = String.Join("", phoneList);` then checking if the phone starts with "911" is a simple string check: `phoneNumber.StartsWith("911")`. Similarly, checking for 10 digits is just `phoneNumber.Length`. Of course, you may wish to introduce input validation (e.g., only numbers allowed). EDIT: Sorry, pretty bad typos there.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair could you make an answer out of that being more specific rather than writing on the comment section? Would help me in a clearer way please.

Comment: What do you mean "as soon as I type 911"? Does it mean you only entered one phone number, "911" into the list? So `i` and `j` both would equal 0. So of course it would jump over the `if (.... && i != j)`.

Comment: @Cleon: Sorry, don't have the time right now to write out a full answer based on the question posed. Just take a look at using `String.Join`, `StartsWith` and `Length`, give it a shot then ask another question if necessary.

Comment: Phone numbers can contain nondigits and can certainly be longer than 10; Oxford University's phone number is +44 1865 270000. You need the + symbol to show where to type in the city code, it might not be at the start.

Comment: Loop through input and remove all spaces / special characters. Then use substring of 0,3 and check if that equals 911

Comment: @Cleon: To resolve your infinite loop on input, don't check against `null`, instead check against an empty string `""`. When you hit "ENTER" without inputting any data, it's empty, not null. (that is, use `while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "")` instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're kind of on the right track. You've got a couple of errors in the code, both logical as well as structurally.

First of all, your while loop goes on forever because it continues until the input is null... which can't happen - at best, the input will be a blank string `""`.

Secondly, you're checking the first three numbers entered of a string (good) against the first three numbers of every string in the list (not good). Instead, you should be checking for `"911"`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var phoneList = new List<string>();
    string input;
    Console.WriteLine("The Phone Number: ");

    while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
    {
        phoneList.Add(input);
    }    

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (phoneList[i].Substring(0, 3) == "911")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT CONSISTENT");
            return;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CONSISTENT");
}
```

It's important to note, however, that this code does not check for any special characters, whitespace, etc... It assumes that input will be something like `1234567890` instead of `12 34 56 78 90`. If you want to get rid of all the whitespace, make sure to use `String.Replace(" ", "")` on each of your inputs before running them through the for loop.

Comment: Indeed this solution does work. But if you type in for example: "9 11" or "91 1" or "9 1 1" it does not work, and even if you go for a "or" operator in the if statement, it will not work. How shall we solve this?

Comment: I addressed this in my answer already. You'll most likely have to use the String.Replace method on the input string, like so: `input = input.Replace(" ","");`

Comment: I dont understand. I just wrote this code: "input = input.Replace(" ", "9 11");
                input = input.Replace("9 1 1", "91 1");"

After the while loop and before the for loop as you said but it still wont work :S

Comment: Let's say `input` is `91 12 34 56 78`. If you use `input = input.Replace(" ", "")`, every blank character will be removed from the input string, so you're left with `9112345678`. This line of code has to be used before you add the input string to the list of phone numbers to check. Use a debugger to step through the code and examine the contents of the inputs before and after the replace function.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop will never be reached since your program cannot get out of the while-loop (input will never be null).

Furthermore, if it would reach the for-loop the algorithm is not correct: it is comparing the first three digits of each phone number with all first three digits of the other phone numbers in the phone number list gathered so far.

A better way to accomplish the task is by checking if the first three characters are not equal to "991". You can add a method to do so, for example called `IsValidPhoneNumber`. This method can later be extended to include more validity checks (since this is quite complex you can use a library like [GlobalPhone](https://github.com/GlobalPhone/GlobalPhone) to do so). Next we only add a number to the phone list if it is valid.

Since your program will not easily go out of the while-loop (input will never be null) you might want to do something with your numbers some time. To do this I added the ability to type "PRINT" and then the list so far will be added.

```
private const string PRINT_PHONE_NUMBERS_IDENTIFIER = "PRINT";
private static readonly List<string> PhoneList = new List<string>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Add phone numbers to phone list (or {PRINT_PHONE_NUMBERS_IDENTIFIER} to print list so far): ");

    string input;
    while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null) // Keeps reading since input will never be null.
    {
        if (input == PRINT_PHONE_NUMBERS_IDENTIFIER)
        {
            PrintAllNumbers();
        }
        else if (IsValidPhoneNumber(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CONSISTENT");
            PhoneList.Add(input);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT CONSISTENT");
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsValidPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
    return !phoneNumber.StartsWith("991");
}

private static void PrintAllNumbers()
{
    if (PhoneList.Any())
    {
        foreach (var phoneNumber in PhoneList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phone list is empty");
    }
}
```

> Add phone numbers to phone list (or PRINT to print list so far):
>   
> PRINT
>   
> Phone list is empty
>   
> 991
>   
> NOT CONSISTENT
>   
> PRINT
>   
> Phone list is empty
>   
> 1234567890
>   
> CONSISTENT
>   
> 1235432665
>   
> CONSISTENT
>   
> PRINT
>   
> 1234567890
>   
> 1235432665

I got a bit carried away already, but you can further improve the program by refactoring the functionality into a separate class. Then you can for example build an office application around it. :)